# Can't Remove Previous Years Contributions from Your GitHub Profile?

Tags: github

I recently opened an old project that had commits from 2019 and pushed it to my GitHub repository. However, when the project was pushed, my GitHub profile displayed that I had contributions in 2019 and 2020 which I did even though I only joined GitHub in 2021. Can you please guide me on how to remove these 2019 and 2020 from my profile? I have amended the commits to 2021, but these years are still showing up.

you can check out my GitHub Profile [here](https://github.com/Turmaxx)

TLDR: 2019 and 2020 year still show up on my profile. I want to know how to remove them.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  Why is it important to you to do this?

Comment: @bk2204 I just wanted it to go back to how it was. It's not urgent.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, if you delete your repository your contributions will also get deleted

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).